# How many categories are involved in my Functor definition

Tags: scala, category-theory

I have a following definition of Functor:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] { 
    def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
object ListFunctor extends Functor[List] { //
    def map[A, B](f: A => B)(data: List[A]): List[B] = data map f
}
```

Assume that `A is Int,B is String ,and F is List`,then f is a function of type: Int=>String, and we get a function List[Int]=>List[String] with `ListFunctor.map(f) _`

Since functor is closely related with Category, and I am now trying to understand category, I would ask how many categories are involved in the ListFunctor if `A is Int,B is String ,and F is List`

I have two possible answers in mind but don't know which one is correct:

1.There are four categories:

```
All possible values of Int forms an Int category

All possible values of String forms a String category

All possible values of List[Int] forms a List[Int] category

All possible values of List[String] forms a List[String] category
```

2. There are two categories

   2.1 Int and String form a category, that is,this category contains all possible values of Int and String

   2.2 List[Int] and List[String] form the other category, that is,this category contains all possible values of List[Int]

I would ask which of the above answers is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Functor in Scala all deal with one and the same category, one where objects are Scala *types* (not individual values) and arrows are Scala functions. This category is usually called **Scala**.

Comment: Thanks @n.m.for the quick answer. What do you mean by `not individual values`in your comments?

Comment: Yes, or at least there's one category where the Functor trait describes functors. One can think of other categories in connection with the Scala language, but this one is the default one.

Comment: "Not individual values" means that 2 or 5 or List(1,2,3) are not objects of any category we want to talk about. Int and List\[Int\] are.

Comment: Understood,thanks @n.m.

Answer (score 1):

There are two categories here:

- The one whose objects are all types in Scala, and whose morphisms are functions `A => B` for all `A` and `B`.
- The one whose objects are types `List[A]` for all `A`, and whose morphisms are functions `List[A] => List[B]` for all `A` and `B`.

A `Functor` is a mapping between categories, and the `ListFunctor` is a functor that maps from the first category to the second.

Comment: It is unusual to present things this way. The second category is a proper subcategory of the first one so we normally just say that ListFunctor is an endofunctor.

Comment: @n.m.If scala has only one category, then every functor is scala is endofunctor?

Comment: @Tom yes it is normal to talk about one category and all endofunctors. The way Ziyang Liu presents it is certanly valid mathematically but IMHO is less useful in practice than the one category view.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about categories in relation to a programming language, we define a category "Scala" where objects are types and morphisms are functions. Following that definition, every functor defined in such as category is an endo-functor.

This means that the `map` function on `Functor` is a morphism from object `A => B`, and the functor definition is a functor from the category of Scala onto itself.

Comment: A Functor in Scala is indeed an endofunctor. A morphism, though, is not necessarily an endomorphism. An endomorphism is a function A => A.

Comment: @Bartosz Thanks for the clarification. Fixed the answer.